# Contentable div not setting background color and padding

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I changed a div to contenteditable. It doesn't set the background color and padding. What am I missing?

```
  <div id="content" contenteditable>                    
  </div>

  #content {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    width: 100%;    
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you are using wrong `ID`

```css
#content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working, check this plnk http://plnkr.co/edit/bIIsEwaycDOZwv3msglq?p=preview